# change all occurrence of word selected after the cursor in vim

Tags: vim

If I have my vim cursor on a word and I want to change all of the occurrences of that particular word that happens after the cursor position.

Also if I select a string  using visual mode and I have to change every occurrence of that string that is there in the file after the cursor position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type `cw` you change the word starting on the cursor position. If you want to change all of them you can previously hit `*` which will search the next occurrence of the word. You can then alternate between pressing `n` to get to the next word and `.` to repeat the change word.

You could also do a `%s/old/new/gc` and confirm or reject each occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make a mapping to populate a substitute command with the word under the cursor like so:

```
" substitute word under the cursor
nnoremap <LEADER>* :%s/\<<C-r><C-w>\>/
```

This mapping includes the word boundaries `\<` and `\>` to make sure you don't replace words that begin with the letters in the word under the cursor. E.g. with the cursor on the word 'shop' in:

```
Go to the shop 
to do some 
shopping, then 
go to another 
shop.
```

Pressing `Leader` + `*` gives:

```
:%s/\<shop\>/
```

Adding your replacement:

```
:%s/\<shop\>/store/g
```

Pressing enter:

```
Go to the store
to do some 
shopping, then 
go to another 
store.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using these mappings for situations where there are few words to change:

```
nnoremap c* *<C-o>cgn
nnoremap c# #<C-o>cgn
```

the <kbd>Ctrl-o</kbd> ensures the current word will be included in the substitution. For more see: `:h Ctrl-o`.